# Make view count for pop up post

Tags: posts, views

I'm using SimpleModal to allow users to click on a post excerpt on my homepage and popup a box showing the full post. However it doesn't count for an actual view of the post when this happens. Is there a way to make wordpress recognize it as a view? I'm using [wp-postviews](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postviews/) to track view counts.

Comment: Some links to the plugins would be useful. You know, some of us don’t know the source code of all plugins ever written. Strange, I know, but it’s true. ;)

Comment: good point sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the plugin does the logging inside the `wp_head` hook:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'process_postviews');
```

so make sure you call `wp_head()` in your pop-up box, or if you can't do that (pop-up is not a html document), then just call the function directly, like:

```
if(function_exists('process_postviews'))
  process_postviews();

// the_content();  ?
```